# How to control Android phone with laptop's mouse and keyboard without lag?

Tags: remote-control, bluetooth-pairing

I tried software called "MyPhoneExplorer" that has mirroring function and using it via Wifi gives mouse input lag. Maybe it's possible to achieve this without lag, like using regular Bluetooth mouse connected to phone. Maybe somehow connect PC with phone via Bluetooth?

Comment: Remote control using Bluetooth was something Microsoft had included in the "Your Phone" Windows app. However the supported devices was very limited and in the end they [dropped this technique it totally](https://www.xda-developers.com/microsoft-your-phone-app-drops-support-bluetooth-low-energy-connection/).

Comment: Why not connect the USB mouse and keyboard directly? Any reason for this? There's no single mirroring app that I know that doesn't have lag.

Comment: a bluetooth keyboard/mouse should of course connected to the phone directly. if you mean screencast and remote controll with pc keyboard/mouse, enable adb over wifi, use scrcpy or vysor